# rake release fail (using gem bundler)

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I published my first rubygem here: https://rubygems.org/gems/blomming_api
(source code here: https://github.com/solyaris/blomming_api)

I used bundler, that create three rake tasks with `bundle gem` command:

```
$ rake -T
rake build    # Build blomming_api-0.3.7.gem into the pkg directory
rake install  # Build and install blomming_api-0.3.7.gem into system gems
rake release  # Create tag v0.3.7 and build and push blomming_api-0.3.7.gem to Rubygems
```

All fine if install locally the gem with `rake install`:

```
$ rake install
blomming_api 0.3.7 built to pkg/blomming_api-0.3.7.gem.
blomming_api (0.3.7) installed.
```

The problem arise when I try to release:

```
$ rake release
blomming_api 0.3.7 built to pkg/blomming_api-0.3.7.gem.
Tagged v0.3.7.
Untagging v0.3.7 due to error.
rake aborted!
Couldn't git push. `git push  2>&1' failed with the following output:

fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>


/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:104:in `perform_git_push'
/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:96:in `git_push'
/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:77:in `block in release_gem'
/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:129:in `tag_version'
/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:77:in `release_gem'
/home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:50:in `block in install'
Tasks: TOP => release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Nevertheless I'm able to publish the gem with successfull `gem push` command:

```
$ gem push pkg/blomming_api-0.3.7.gem
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
Successfully registered gem: blomming_api (0.3.7)
```

I presume that problem is on the git push remote configuration...
Any idea to help me configure git to let rake release run ?

BTW, I already configured my rubygems credentials on /home/solyaris/.gem
and git push on github run ok.
I know... my git reluctance is big ;-)
Thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 12):

The command `rake release` attempts to push the code to the remote repository (implicitly assuming you're using git) and create a tag.

In your case, it looks like there is no git remote configured for your repository and the task fails.

I personally don't like such task. I tend to use

```
$ rake build
```

to build the package, then

```
$ gem push pkg/...
```

to publish the gem to RubyGems.

If you want to use `rake release` I suggest you to override the default implementation to skip/replace/customize the Git commit.

Comment: thanks Simone. I use gem push me too. the problem so could be re-asked: how to set the git remote to point the rubygems repository ?

Comment: RubyGems has no git repository. You can't point the repo to RubyGems. The task is assuming you are versioning your library in a git repo, such as on GitHub or elsewhere.

Comment: `rake release` is awesome and automates what you should be doing anyway -- creating tags in git for each release.

Answer (score 4):

`rake release` will attempt to tag your gem in git and push it to your remote. Sounds like you aren't configured to do `git push` without specifying the remote.

Try this to fix: `git push -u origin master`

If you can do `git push` after that without an error, `rake release` should work as well, although you might need to bump the version number of your gem if you've already pushed it to ruby gems, as I think ruby gems complains if you try to release a gem of the same version.

Comment: FYI - The error output message I saw suggests to run `git push --set-upstream origin master`, which works as well (I believe the two commands are equivalent).